# How to set Aviary crop presets in ios version?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, aviary

I can find mention of setting [cropPresets](http://www.aviary.com/web-documentation#constructor-config-croppresets) in the web version of Aviary (and feather_crop_values in android), but nothing in the ios sdk.
Is there anyway to set the crop presets/values in the ios version, or is this exclusive to the web and android versions?

There is an option to pass NSDictionary options, but the toolset order is the only example given. I tried doing an dictionary with the key "cropPresets" and a value that was an NSArray with an entry of "48x48" as NSString, but it seemed to ignore it and display the default crop presets. I suppose I could keep shooting in the dark, unless someone has a better idea?

Comment: CFD, can you share your binding project for MonoTouch?

Comment: (Sorry I haven't checked my notifications in awhile.) I found one on google back when I asked this question. Due to an Apple rules change Aviary had to change some things and I don't think the one I have would work anymore. I did a fresh google today and found a github repo claiming to have bindings for the current rev [link](https://github.com/theonlylawislove/MonoTouch.Aviary). I have not had a chance to try it myself.

Comment: https://github.com/theonlylawislove/MonoTouch.Aviary

Comment: Of course if I take the time to look closer at it, it appears to be your own repo, so I guess you already knew that :) For those that stumble upon this posting, there are also more bindings available on github [here as well](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings) but for Aviary see Paul's link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same Problem just a view days ago.

So i wrote them an e-mail.
They answered me following:

> Customizing the crop options actually isn't yet officially supported
>   on this platform (although we do support it for web and Android, which
>   may be contributing to the confusion here). That said, we have this
>   coming up soon in our roadmap and you should have no problem including
>   only one crop size once that update is available.

So keep an eye out for the new update!

Answer (score 2):

Just following up for those who encounter the same problem: Aviary for iOS now supports custom crop presets so go right ahead and use it, as documented. I just coded up a test and it worked fine.

http://www.aviary.com/ios/documentation#customization

Comment: As its written, this seems like it should have just been a comment

Answer (score 1):

Just had to solve the same problem, so I thought I might share the code (it's included in their sample code: https://github.com/AviaryInc/Aviary-iOS-Sample-App/blob/master/AviaryDemo-iOS/AFSDKDemoViewController.m ) :

```
// Set Custom Crop Sizes
[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setOptionValue:@NO forKey:@"editor.tool.crop.enableOriginal"];
[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setOptionValue:@YES forKey:@"editor.tool.crop.enableCustom"];
NSDictionary * fourBySix = @{kAFCropPresetHeight : @(4.0f), kAFCropPresetWidth : @(6.0f)};
NSDictionary * fiveBySeven = @{kAFCropPresetHeight : @(5.0f), kAFCropPresetWidth : @(7.0f)};
NSDictionary * square = @{kAFCropPresetName: @"Square", kAFCropPresetHeight : @(1.0f), kAFCropPresetWidth : @(1.0f)};
[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setOptionValue:@[square, fourBySix, fiveBySeven] forKey:@"editor.tool.crop.presets"];
```